Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation
It seems that with the recent Windows Update, for systems that have dual-boot is not letting grub start, showing the message: Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation.
Does anyone know what can I do to fix this?

I got this on an old installation of openSUSE Tumbleweed after booting a live USB of Fedora 40.

Okay, I managed to fix it!
I followed the instructions in: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-revocations-boot-process/34996
In case this can help anyone, here is what worked for me:

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS
Log into your Ubuntu user and open a terminal
Delete the SBAT policy with: sudo mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete
Reboot your PC and log back into Ubuntu to update the SBAT policy
Reboot and then re-enable secure boot in your BIOS.

Edit #1:
This is only available for versions after Ubuntu 22.10
Edit #2:
I also followed this guide recommended by user Mr. T which modifies the Windows Registry to no longer do SBAT modifications in future updates.
In a Windows CMD with admin permissions run the following command:
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\SBAT /v OptOut /d 1 /t REG_DWORD


Hmm... I'd say better yet is to move Windows into a Virtualbox VM; similar problems will disappear forever. Even better; use it only for what is absolutely necessary and nothing else.

I get
EFI variables are not supported on this system
when running sudo mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete

@SilaSiebert do you know if your BIOS is UEFI or Legacy?

For step 4. Is the SBAT policy updated automatically after restarting Ubuntu or should I do it manually?

@JoseMiralles logging back into Ubuntu updates the policy automatically.

Just to clarify, these actions will disable SBAT protection. Can you restore sbat-policy to latest? And will Ubuntu 24.04.1 update Shim/Grub bootloader to follow requirements of new SBAT policy or everyone with Ubuntu 24.04 need to update Shim/Grub apart from Ubuntu after 24.04.1 installed?

Thanks @ManuelAlejandroDiazZapata this worked for me, too! Now I am not a very experienced Ubuntu user, so I hope this question isn't too basic, but I was wondering whether having completed these steps will leave my machine a bit more vulnerable to malware? Thanks again!

@ubuntu_ambassador according to the post I linked, the SBAT protection gets updated to 'previous' when you do steps 3 and 4: "Please note that booting the new shim after a completed reset will reapply the “previous” policy again." and does not leave it disabled.

Thanks this worked in Debian 12 as well for me

Yeah on delete the policy would then be set to previous by default, so I guess it buys some time, but what happens when at some point, “latest” is replaced by another update and then becomes “previous” ? The shim better be updated in the meantime…

What can I do if disable Secure Boot option is not active (greyed out) in my BIOS?

Regarding my previous comment - setting Supervisor Password solved the problem

This is hard for many people, which do not have the required experience, to fix that.
Is this intended by Microsoft against Linux users?

@NovHak Doesn't the step Prevent Future SBAT Updates in Windows address this problem?

@Mr.T  Thanks a lot for the resource! I will try it and update the answer accordingly!

Under 20.04.1 this does not work. Step 1 gets me to GRUB, but step 3 reports mokutil: unrecognized option '--set-sbat-policy'. "This mokutil feature is only available in Ubuntu 22.10 and newer." I suggest you update this answer to suggest that older Ubuntu need to upgrade (or run without secure boot).

@Mr.T It should indeed. However, if anything, this should serve as a reminder that each and every Linux distro shouldn’t have to rely on MS signature, and have a procedure to have their own signature added to the UEFI database (i.e. KEK variable). Something that MS wants to avoid at all costs, hence keeping the upper hand on nearly every PC’s authorized startup procedure…

This is taken from Akeo's answer here.
I think your question is easy to answer:

As its version number indicates, Ubuntu 24.04 was released in April 2024.
The Microsoft update you appear to be talking about (KB5041160) was released in August 2024.

We should therefore assume that if a Windows update from August 2024 talks about fixing a Secure Boot vulnerability in the UEFI Shim, it is likely to apply to the UEFI Shim used in an ISO that was released 4 months prior, such as the one used in the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO.
Now, Ubuntu does tend to produce refreshes of major releases, where they update the software (and can update bootloaders as well), which they will suffix with a .1, .2 etc. The24.04.1 refresh was not released until the end of August 2024, so the 24.04 ISO you are using is still the April 2024 one, which most likely uses a Shim that has not been patched for the vulnerability that the Microsoft August update is trying to address (and therefore prevents vulnerable Shim bootloaders to run through SBAT).
And, as you mention, since you do not run a dual boot installation, the update did install the SBAT update on your system, thereby most likely preventing any Shim based Linux boot media, that uses a pre 2024.08 Shim, from booting.
Try using the Ubuntu 24.04.1 ISO and please report back how you go!

Anther solution to this issue is to disable secure boot completely in UEFI/BIOS.

in my EXO system, at boot it show a message to press F7 and after pressing F7 and ENTER to the password, it get into Windows directly

Great, easy solution, however if you have BitLocker enabled on your Windows System Volume, you now have an Ubuntu-only laptop.

The shim SBAT data failed error means that Shim has blocked itself from executing because it found its own version on the SBAT block list. The SBAT block list is essentially a list of software versions that have security vulnerabilities and hence shouldn't be run (for details, see What is SBAT and why does everyone suddenly care?). In particular, the SBAT list was updated by Microsoft on 20th August 2024 to block Shim version 15.7 because of the CVE-2023-40547 remote code execution vulnerability.
The solution to this is to upgrade Shim to the latest version 15.8.
First turn off Secure Boot in the EFI firmware and  boot your Linux install (you can re-enable Secure Boot after upgrading the Shim). The following commands must be run as root in a terminal.
Check efibootmgr -v so see what your boot order is, and which EFI path is executed - probably /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi, but if your install is on a removable drive it might be /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi (if you are running systemd-boot or Debian or something else then look in /boot/efi/EFI/*).
To check the version of the installed Shim, run:
# strings /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi | grep '$Version:'
$Version: 15.7 $

If the version is 15.7 (as above), then you must upgrade to 15.8. You can do this automatically by upgrading the shim with apt:
apt update
apt upgrade --reinstall shim-signed

Or manually by just copying the newer shim over the old one:
# cp /usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

Now check the Shim version:
# strings /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi | grep '$Version:'
$Version: 15.8 $

Reboot and re-enable Secure Boot in the EFI firmware. Everything should now work.
