Bootloading Ubuntu 24.04 ISO error SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation without removing SBAT policy and disabling Secure Boot
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 (latest ISO from official website). I made bootable USB (UEFI) GPT - tried rufus and Ventoy. But when I load from USB with UEFI and Secure Boot on allowed 3rd party certificates (not only Microsoft) I get an error on boot saying: Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation.
Microsoft says in latest update:

This update applies SBAT to systems that run Windows. This stops vulnerable Linux EFI (Shim bootloaders) from running. This SBAT update will not apply to systems that dual-boot Windows and Linux. After the SBAT update is applied, older Linux ISO images might not boot. If this occurs, work with your Linux vendor to get an updated ISO image.

Of course, I'm not currently on dual-boot system, so I run only Windows and this update was applied. It says this update will stop vulnerable Linux EFI (Shim bootloaders) from running. But I don't understand how Ubuntu didn't know their bootloader in latest ISO is vulnerable!
Also they say If this occurs, work with your Linux vendor to get an updated ISO image. But I don't know how to get support from Ubuntu vendor about their vulnerable ISO and get updated version so I'm here.
I do not want to remove SBAT policy because if it was set then it is needed by security update.
Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation does not answer to my question because the answer is to remove SBAT policy or disable Secure Boot that I do not want to do!
Is there newer installer media without this error?

@user535733 secure boot just stops vulnerable EFI from running as Microsoft says. So when and where can we download ISO with EFI not vulnerable and allowed by SBAT?

@user535733 if you read carefully similar question the answer to this is not helpful. It advises to delete sbat policy and allow old grub and shim to start ubuntu. My question is about not deleing seat policy, I want to know if there is another way to solve it or maybe I don't know about new ISO from Ubuntu that does not contain vulnerable bootloader.

Repeating a question due to a disliked answer is strongly discouraged here.

@user535733 my question is not repeating. I already noticed that many users on Stack platforms are unfriendly. But I'm waiting if someone knows an answer to my question how to fix this error WITHOUT deleting sbat policy!

The question is the same, therefore it's a duplicate. If someone has an answer that involves not removing the policy, it should be added to the duplicate question.

@ArturMeinild I don't think so. It is easier to answer to specific question than guessing on coffee grounds that an answer needed in general question. Thank you for voting down though :)

@Raffles with secure boot disabled it works but I don't want to disable secure boot. Long times ago it was needed, but now it is unacceptable for me to disable secure boot permanently.

Answer from a Canonical Engineering manager: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-self-check-failed-mitigating-the-impact-of-shim-15-7-revocation-on-the-ubuntu-boot-process-for-devices-running-windows/47378 explains the problem and the solution.

I think your question is easy to answer:

As its version number indicates, Ubuntu 24.04 was released in April 2024.
The Microsoft update you appear to be talking about (KB5041160) was released in August 2024.

We should therefore assume that if a Windows update from August 2024 talks about fixing a Secure Boot vulnerability in the UEFI Shim, it is likely to apply to the UEFI Shim used in an ISO that was released 4 months prior, such as the one used in the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO.
Now, Ubuntu does tend to produce refreshes of major releases, where they update the software (and can update bootloaders as well), which they will suffix with a .1, .2 etc. The24.04.1 refresh is currently scheduled for 29 August 2024, so the 24.04 ISO you are using is still the April 2024 one, which most likely uses a Shim that has not been patched for the vulnerability that the Microsoft August update is trying to address (and therefore prevents vulnerable Shim bootloaders to run through SBAT).
And, as you mention, since you do not run a dual boot installation, the update did install the SBAT update on your system, thereby most likely preventing any Shim based Linux boot media, that uses a pre 2024.08 Shim, from booting.

Then I will wait for Ubuntu 24.04.1 to be released as soon as August 29 if I recall correctly. Thank you!

Just a follow up question: Do you remember/know if you installed KB5041160 manually on your system? By the looks of it, it doesn't seem to be installed automatically (at least on Windows 11), so I wouldn't mind knowing if you or your system administrator manually applied that one.

Please consider also adding an appropriate answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523438/verifying-shim-sbat-data-failed-security-policy-violation

@Akeo It was installed for me as Patch Tuesday update automatically on Windows 11 23H2 KB5041585 - a newer version than previous KB.

@ubuntu_ambassador, you are correct. I just tested on a Windows 11 system that had received last Tuesday's update and got the SBAT Security Violation. Even if Ubuntu is hopefully going to be updated soon, this is going to affect a lot of people trying to boot Linux distributions...

@Akeo I thought about it too. The only way to resolve it is to wait 24.04.1 version and download new ISO. I'm new to Ubuntu updates but I think it won't update Grub bootloader later with Ubuntu 24.04.1 version if I install 24.04 now with Secure Boot disabled.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

@ubuntu_ambassador, I would assume that, as part of Ubuntu system updates, the Shim used by the installed system will be updated (sorry I don't actually have a system to test this on), so you should be able to re-enable Secure Boot after you installed and ran a full system update. At any rate, you can just install the system with Secure Boot disabled, update it, try to re-enable Secure Boot and see if you run into the error. If not, then you're good to go. If you do, then you'll have to wait for a system update that fixes the Shim to re-enable Secure Boot.
